# JavaScript Animation Sync

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two group of HTML elements. Font color of each element in **Group 2** automatically jump one to another. Now I want it to synced with **Group 1** which is static and need to be changing with **Group 2**'s slide.

Whenever I click on elements from group 1, I want elements in group 2 also change.

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h2>Group 1</h2>

<ul id="group-1">
  <li class="active">Trigar 1</li>
  <li>Trigar 2</li>
  <li>Trigar 3</li>
  <li>Trigar 4</li>
  <li>Trigar 5</li>
</ul>

<h2>Group 2</h2>

<ul id="group-2">
  <li class="active">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/17sz2cv2/1/

Comment: Where's your JavaScript code? It's a js question and there's not a line of it

Comment: Let alone there's an animation anywhere...

Answer (score 1):

Trigger this when the active element in #group-1 has been set:

```
$("#group-1").children("li").each(function(index){
   if($(this).hasClass("active")) {
      $("#group-2 li:nth-child("+(index+1)+")").addClass("active");
   }
});
```

Also see http://jsfiddle.net/17sz2cv2/4/